# why this code isn't returning any value in TextView cannot get any value from json

Tags: java, android, json

In this code the TextView field cannot have any value when pass to json and the  warning is could not convert json object into json array

```
String json = strListingsDetails;

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).toString());
            JSONArray dataListArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DataList");

            if (dataListArray != null && dataListArray.length() != 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < dataListArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = dataListArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String listingId = jsonObject1.getString("ListingID");
                    String specification = jsonObject1.getString("Specifications");
                    String description = jsonObject1.getString("Description");
                    String manufacturer = jsonObject1.getString("Manufacturer");
                    String brand = jsonObject1.getString("Brand");
                    String machineType = jsonObject1.getString("ManchineType");
                    String condition = jsonObject1.getString("Condition");
                    String yearOfMfg = jsonObject1.getString("YearofMfg");
                    String Price=jsonObject1.getString("Price");
                    String ShowPrice=jsonObject1.getString("ShowPrice");
                    String country = jsonObject1.getString("Country");
                    String state = jsonObject1.getString("State");
                    String city = jsonObject1.getString("City");
                    String qty = jsonObject1.getString("Qty");
                    String height = jsonObject1.getString("Height");
                    String width = jsonObject1.getString("Width");
                    String length = jsonObject1.getString("Length");
                    String weight = jsonObject1.getString("Weight");
                    String warranty = jsonObject1.getString("Warranty");
                    String expiredOn = jsonObject1.getString("ExpiredOn");
```

Comment: Please attach the Json to take the reference.

Comment: Firstly attach the Json which you are trying to parse and then ask for the relevant error

Comment: As others said please show your JSON data. so we could give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> could not convert json object into json array

You are trying to parse JSON string which is JSON Object and not an Array

Try like this.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray dataListArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DataList");
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: are you getting the same error? can you please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

please match your json as below what i guess:

```
[
{
    "DataList": [
        {
            "ListingID": "value",
            "Specifications": "value",
            "Description": "value",
            "Manufacturer": "value",
            "Brand": "value"
             ...
        }
    ]
}
]
```

log your json, you will be find the answer

Comment: all are same. how to log json.

Comment: update your answer, add the log info ,you can do like this.
String json = strListingsDetails;
 Log.d(TAG, "json: "+json);